# Finding a cycle in a DFS directed graph

Tags: cycle, depth-first-search

I'm trying to find a cycle in an directed graph using a dfs search. I'm reading in the file from a text file that holds all the neighbors of a vertex. Whenever I call the cycle_exists method I keep getting all false, so the answer never changes.

```
Vertex.py 
"""
__version__ = 'October 2015'

Vertex class reads in our graph and
performs a depth first search on it
and performs the transitive closure operation.
Vertex class also checks for cycles in our graph.
"""


import sys
class Graph:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize the variable used in Graph
        """
        self.dfsPaths = [] #list for dfsPaths
        self.VertexList = {} #list for adjacent vertices


    def readInputGraph(self, inputFile):
        """
        Reads specified input file and stores in
        adjacency list
        :param inputFile: file to be rad in
        :return: the VertexList
        """
        file = open(inputFile, 'r') #open the file and read it
        for line in file: #for each element in the file
            (vertex,val) = line.split() #vertex gets first value in the line, val gets second
            if vertex not in self.VertexList: #if vertex not in VertexList
               self.VertexList[vertex] = set([val]) #add adjacent pairs
            else:   #else
                self.VertexList.get(vertex).add(val) #add the values


        for i in list(self.VertexList.keys()): #for each element in the list of the vertex keys
            for j in self.VertexList[i]: # for each vertex that's in i
                if j not in self.VertexList: #if j is not in the vertex list
                    self.VertexList[j] = set() #we add it to the vertex list

        return self.VertexList #return list of adjacent vertices

    def dfsSearch(self, graph, start, end, path = []):
        """
        Performs a depth first search on
        the graph that is read in from the file
        :param graph: the graph that we are performing the search on
        :param start: the starting vertex
        :param end: the target vertex
        :param path: a list of the paths
        :return: the paths from the search
        """
        path = path + [start] #path
        if start == end: #if the start element and end element are the same
            return [path] #return the list of paths
        if start not in graph: #if the start element is not in the graph
            print( 'Not Found')#prints out not found
            return [] #return an empty list
        paths = [] #path list
        for node in graph[start]: #for node in the graph

            if node not in path: #if not in the path
                newpaths = self.dfsSearch(graph, node, end, path) #new paths we found

                for newpath in newpaths: #for each new path in the list of new paths
                    paths.append(newpath) #add the new path to our list of paths

        paths.sort() #sort our paths
        self.cycle_exists(graph)
        #print(self.cycle_exists(graph))

        return paths #return our paths


    def cycle_exists(self, graph): # -graph is our graph.
        color = { node : "white" for node in graph}  #color all nodes white to begin with
        found_cycle = False # found_cycle set to false

        for node in graph: # for each node in graph.
            if color[node]:#if the color[node] is white
                self.dfs_visit(graph, node, color, found_cycle) #we call the dfs_visit method
            if found_cycle:#if a cycle is found
                found_cycle = True
                break#break
        return found_cycle #return the true or false

    def dfs_visit(self,graph, node, color, found_cycle):
        #print(color)
        if found_cycle: # if a cycle is found return to the cycle_exists method
            return
        color[node] = "gray"#else color the node gray
        for neighbor in graph[node]: #for every neighbor in the graph of the node
            if color[neighbor] == "gray": #If neighbor is gray
                found_cycle = True # then a cycle exists.
                return
            if color[neighbor] == "white": #if the neighbor is white
                #print(color[neighbor])
                self.dfs_visit(graph, neighbor, color, found_cycle)# call dfs_visit .

        color[node] = "black"# color the original node black
```

GraphDriver.py
    from Vertex import *
    import sys

```
class GraphDriver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = Graph()

def main():
    graph = Graph()
    inFile = sys.argv[1]
    d = graph.readInputGraph(inFile)

    userInput = input("Enter a source and destination:")

    dog = userInput.split(" ", -1)


    for path in graph.dfsSearch(d, dog[0], dog[1]):
        print(path)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Input.txt
0 1
0 6
1 2
1 5
2 3
2 4
4 3
4 0
5 4
6 5

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it expects the boolean variable `found_cycle` to be passed by-reference to `dfs_visit`. However, Python does pass by-value ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494696/are-pythons-bools-passed-by-value/1494728), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)). Therefore, when `dfs_visit` sets the parameter `found_cycle` to `True`, this modification will not affect the `found_cycle` variable passed into `dfs_visit` by the caller.

You can fix this by changing `dfs_visit` to return whether a cycle was found:

```
    def cycle_exists(self, graph):
        color = { node : "white" for node in graph}

        for node in graph:
            if color[node] == "white":
                if self.dfs_visit(graph, node, color):
                    return True

        return False

    def dfs_visit(self,graph, node, color):
        color[node] = "gray"

        for neighbor in graph[node]:
            if color[neighbor] == "gray":
                return True
            if color[neighbor] == "white":
                if self.dfs_visit(graph, neighbor, color):
                    return True

        color[node] = "black"
        return False
```

### Background information

Regarding the passing of boolean variables, consider the following example:

```
def f(my_bool):
  my_bool = True

my_bool = False
f(my_bool)

print(my_bool)
```

This code will print `False`. In the global scope, the variable `my_bool` is initialized with `False` and is then passed to `f`. It is passed by-value, so in `f` the parameter `my_bool` receives the value `False`. However, this variable `my_bool` is unrelated to the variable `my_bool` outside `f`. So modifying the `my_bool` in `f` does not affect the `my_bool` outside `f`.

Note that this does not mean that you cannot pass references to objects, only that the reference is passed by-value. Consider the following example:

```
class MyObject:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 13

def f(my_object):
  my_object.x = 17

def g(my_object):
  my_object = MyObject()
  my_object.x = 19

my_object = MyObject()

print(my_object.x)
f(my_object)
print(my_object.x)
g(my_object)
print(my_object.x)
```

This example prints:

```
13
17
17
```

In the global scope, the variable `my_object` is initialized with an instance of `MyObject`. The constructor of `MyObject` initializes the member variable `x` to `13`, which is the first printed value. The `my_object` variable is then passed to the function `f`. The variable is passed by-value, so the variable `my_object` in `f` is a different variable than the variable `my_object` in the global scope. However, both point to the same instance of `MyObject`. So when `f` sets `my_object.x = 17`, the next `print` in the global scope will show this value.

Next, in the global scope the variable `my_object` is passed to `g`. Again, the variable is passed by-value, so the variable `my_object` in `g` is different from the variable `my_object` in the global scope, but both point to the same instance of `MyObject`. In `g` the `my_object` variable is then assigned a new instance of `MyObject`. This does not affect the `my_object` in the global scope, which still points to the previous instance of `MyObject`. Therefore, the final `print` in the global scope will still show the `17` that has been assigned to the `x` of the first instance of `MyObject`, not the `19` that was assigned in `g` to the `x` in the second instance of `MyObject`.

So this is why e.g. your `color` variable is not affected by the same problem as your `found_cycle` variable. For `color`, you pass by-value for each call to `dfs_visit`, as for `found_cycle`, but you never assign a new value to `color` in `dfs_visit`. Therefore, the modifications done to `color` are done to the same object as pointed to by the original `color` variable in the `cycle_exists` function.