# Why does not the + operator change a list while .append() does?

Tags: python, list, append, concatenation

I'm working through Udacity and Dave Evans introduced an exercise about list properties

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]

list1=list1+[6]
print(list1)
list2.append(6)
print(list2)

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]

def proc(mylist):
    mylist = mylist + [6]

def proc2(mylist):
    mylist.append(6)

# Can you explain the results given by the four print statements below? Remove
# the hashes # and run the code to check.

print (list1)
proc(list1)
print (list1)

print (list2)
proc2(list2)
print (list2)
```

The output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

So in a function the adding a 6 to the set doesn't show but it does when not in a function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So in a function the adding a 6 to the set doesn't show but it does when not in a function?

No, that is not what happens.

What happens is that, when you execute `mylist = mylist + [6]`, you are effectively creating an entirely new list and putting it in the local `mylist` variable. This `mylist` variable will vanish after the execution of the function and the newly created list will vanish as well.

OTOH when you execute `mylist.append(6)` you do not create a new list. You get the list already in the `mylist` variable and add a new element to this same list. The result is that the list (which is pointed by `list2` too) will be altered itself. The `mylist` variable will vanish again, but in tis case you altered the original list.

Let us see if a more visual explanation can help you :)

## What happens when you call `proc()`

When you write `list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` you are creating a new list object (at the right side of the equals sign) and creating a new variable, `list1`, which will point to this object.

[image: Creating new list instance and global variable]

Then, when you call `proc()`, you create another new variable, `mylist`, and since you pass `list1` as parameter, `mylist` will point to the same object:

[image: Calling method creates local variable]

However, the operation `mylist + [6]` *creates a whole new list object* whose contents are the contents of the object pointed by `mylist` plus the content of the following list object - that is, `[6]`. Since you attribute this new object to `mylist`, our scenario changes a bit and `mylist` does not point to the same object pointed by `list1` anymore:

[image: mylist points to new list object]

What I have not said is that `mylist`  is a *local variable*: it will disappear after the end of the `proc()` function. So, when the `proc()` execution ended, the `mylist` is gone:

[image: mylist is gone]

Since no other variable points to the object generated by `mylist + [6]`, it will disappear, too (since the garbage collector* will collect it):

[image: GC collects the list]

Note that, in the end, the object pointed by `list1` is not changed.

## What happens when you call `proc2()`

Everything changes when you call `proc2()`. At first, it is the same thing: you create a list...

[image: Creating new list instance and global variable]

...and pass it as a parameter to a function, which will generate a local variable:

[image: Calling method creates local variable]

However, instead of using the `+` concatenation operator, which generates a new list, you apply the `append()` method to the existing list. The `append()` method *does not create a new object*; instead, it _changes the existing one:

[image: Appending a value to a list]

After the end of the function, the local variable will disappear, but the original object pointed by it and by `list1` will be already altered:

[image: It is still altered]

Since it is still pointed by `list1`, the original list is not destroyed.

**EDIT**: if you want to take a look at all this stuff happening **before your eyes** just go to [this radically amazing simulator](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1+=+%5B1,2,3,4%5D%0Alist2+=+%5B1,2,3,4%5D%0A%0Adef+proc%28mylist%29:%0A++++mylist+=+mylist+++%5B6%5D%0A%0Adef+proc2%28mylist%29:%0A++++mylist.append%286%29%0A%0A#+Can+you+explain+the+results+given+by+the+four+print+statements+below?%2bRemove%0A#%2bthe%2bhashes%2b#%2band%2brun%2bthe%2bcode%2bto%2bcheck.%0A%0Aprint%2b%28list1%29%0Aproc%28list1%29%0Aprint%2b%28list1%29%0A%0Aprint%2b%28list2%29%0Aproc2%28list2%29%0Aprint%2b%28list2%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=16):

[image]

* If you do not know what is garbage collector... well, you will discover soon after understanding your own question.

Comment: There is also good [service](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit) to go python code step by step and look at all variables in browser! Very close to what you wrote, @brandizzi

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference has a way better explanation as well!

Comment: your answer is closer to [the truth](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) than the one you've linked in the comment.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian what a wonderful page! I believe you want to point to [this section](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables), right? The "tag" metaphor is really great.

Comment: note that the garbage collector is not the one responsible for freeing that list. Rather, the refcount of the list hits 0 and the memory is thus freed right away. python's garbage collector is only there to break reference cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Variables in python can always be thought of as references.  When you call a function with an argument, you are passing in a reference to the actual data.

When you use the assignment operator (`=`), you're assigning that name to refer to an entirely new object.  So, `mylist = mylist + [6]` creates a new list containing the old contents of mylist, as well as 6, and assigns the variable mylist to refer to the new list.  list1 is still pointing to the old list, so nothing changes.

On the other hand, when you use .append, that is actually appending an element to the list that the variable refers to - it is not assigning anything new to the variable.  So your second function modifies the list that list2 refers to.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, in the first case in function `proc` you would only be able to change the global list by assignment if you declared

```
global mylist
```

first and did not pass `mylist` as a parameter. However, in this case you'd get an error message that `mylist` is global and local:
`name 'mylist' is local and global`. What happens in `proc` is that a local list is created when the assignment takes place. Since local variables go away when the function ends, the effect of any changes to the local list doesn't propagate to the rest of the program when it is printed out subsequently.

But in the second function `proc2` you are *modifying* the list by appending rather than assigning to it, so the `global` keyword is not required and changes to the list show elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the comprehensive answers already given, it's also worth being aware that if you want the same looking syntax as:

```
mylist = mylist + [6]
```

...but still want the list to be updated "in place", you can do:

```
mylist += [6]
```

Which, while it looks like it would do the same thing as the first version, is *actually* the same as:

```
mylist.extend([6])
```

(Note that `extend` takes the contents of an iterable and adds them one by one, whereas `append` takes whatever it is given and adds that as a single item. See [append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend) for a full explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

This, in one form or another, is a very common question. I took a whack at explaining Python parameter passing myself [a couple days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694608/how-does-calling-work-in-python/10694799#10694799). Basically, one of these creates a new list and the other modifies the existing one. In the latter case, all variables that refer to the list "see" the change because it's still the same object.

Answer (score 0):

In the third line, you did this

```
list1=list1+[6]
```

So, when you did the below after the above line,

```
print (list1)
```

which printed list1 that you created at the start and proc procedure which adds list1 + [6] which is creating a new list inside the function proc. Where as when you are appending [6], you are not creating a new list rather you are appending a list item to already existing list.

But, keep in mind. In line 7, you again created the list

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

Now you wanted to print the list1 by calling it explicitly, which will print out the list1 that you reinitialized again but not the previous one.