# Why does the content of a tuple changes when I append to a list inside of it but does not change when I update a variable?

Tags: python, list, append, tuples, variable-assignment

```
myVar = ["jhhj", "hgc"]
myTuple = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], myVar)
myVar.append('lololol')
print myTuple
```

Why and how can this tuple be modified by appending after construction?

```
myVar = "lol"
myTuple = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], myVar)
myVar = "lolol"
print myTuple
```

Why is this going to print out `([1,2,3], [4,5,6], "lol")` instead of `([1,2,3], [4,5,6], "lolol")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, let me try to explain with some images.

In Python, everything is an object. Those objects are *referenced* by variables. Some kinds of objects, such as lists and tuples, just store references to other objects.

That said, when you execute

```
myVar = ["jhhj", "hgc"]
myTuple = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], myVar)
```

You get more or less this scenario:

[image: A tuple pointing to three lists; a list pointing to two strings]

Each object is represented by a box/rectangle. We have two string objects, `"jhhj"` and `"hgc"`. Also, we have a list object, pointed by the variable `myVar`; this list object points to both string objects. Also, we have a tuple object, referenced by `myTuple`; this tuple object points two other lists and the list referenced by `myVar`.

When you execute

```
myVar.append('lololol')
```

what does happen? Well, the list object (that is incidentally pointed by `myVar`) starts to referenced one more value, the string object `"lololol"`:

[image: A tuple pointing to three lists; a list pointing to two strings; a new string is added to the list]

Note that `myVar` still references the list object. What happened is that the list object *changed*. You can look at this list object both from `myVar` or from the tuple, you will see the same object with the same change.

OTOH, when you execute

```
myVar = "lol"
myTuple = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], myVar)
```

You get something like this:

[image: A tuple pointing to two lists and a string, also pointed by a variable]

Now `myVar` points to the string object `"lol"`, as well the tuple references it at its third position. Now, if you execute

```
myVar = "lolol"
```

you are just making `myVar` to point to another object. The tuple object still points to `"lol"` as before:

[image: A tuple pointing to two lists and a string, also pointed by a variable. The variable now references another string.]

So, if you attribute a new value to a variable, it will just change the value pointed by this variable. The previous value referenced by the variable will still exist* and any other variable or object pointing to it will stay pointing to it. Just the attributed variable will change.

PS: Also, [I answered a vaguely related question some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748158/why-does-the-operator-not-change-a-list-while-append-does/10748191#10748191). You may find the answer helpful.

* Except if it is collected by the garbage collector, but this is another long history.

Answer (score 5):

All things in python are objects.

So when you do your original assignment

`myVar = "lol"`

you are giving myVar a reference to the object "lol"

You then create a tuple.  This tuple in the third slot has a reference to "lol"

Then you create a new object "lolol" and give myVar a reference to it.  The tuple retains its original reference to "lol"

Comment: so how come appending a list later in the program modifies the original tuple?

Comment: You are modifying the list object inside the tuple

Comment: You're not modifying the tuple. You're modifying the list members of a tuple. A slightly inaccurate, but helpful way to look at it is that a tuple `([1,2], [3,4])` is really `(address_to_list1, address_to_list2)` You can't change the addresses, but the lists are separate, mutable objects.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable, so you would need to construct a new tuple if you wanted to modify one of its members...

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable but you can concatenate them together like :

```
var a = (1, 2)
var b = a + (3, 4)
```

Comment: how come appending the list myVar later in the program modifies the original tuple?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, when you create the tuple you're copying a reference to whatever object `myvar` was at the time.

In the first case, `myvar` is a mutable object. You can change the object after a reference to it has been stored in the tuple.

In the second case, `myvar` is an immutable string. You can't change the object, but you can change what `myvar` itself refers to. That doesn't change the object that is contained within the tuple though.

Answer (score 1):

There have been some great points in other answers that I won't re-iterate yet again, explaining the difference between *names* and *objects*. All I think is missing is spelling out when some Python code is operating on names and when it is operating on objects.

A key thing that you need to understand though is that the *only* thing that affects names directly is assignment statements[1]. An assignment statement rebinds the name to point to a different object. A name appearing in *any* other context is just a simple standing for whatever object the name is bound to when that line of code is executed.

Lets look at this line from your example:

```
myTuple = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], myVar)
```

`myTuple` appears on the left side of the assignment statement, so the *name* `myTuple` is what's being affected there. `myVar` on the other hand is inside an expression, so it's the *object* `myVar` is bound to that is the third element of the tuple, **not** the name `myVar`.

Consequently, whatever happens later to the *name* `myVar` has no effect whatsoever on the tuple. But as long as the third element of the tuple and `myVar` refer to the same object, changing that *object* (through either `myVar` or the tuple) will obviously affect what you get when you look at the object through either reference.

---

[1] For advanced study, `def` and `class` statements are also "assignment statements" (they create a function or a class and then assign it to the name).

Also, operators like `+=`, `*=`, etc are *sometimes* assignment statements and sometimes not, depending on the type of the object currently referred to by the name on the LHS:

```
myList = []
myList += ['this calls a method on a list object which mutates it in place; the name is not changed']

myInt = 1
myInt += 10  # This rebinds myInt to refer to a new object 11; the object 1 is not changed
```