# Dictionary retrieved by function which reads a pickle file raises KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

What I have is 3 dictionaries dumping with pickle to 3 different files. I had originally just written a read and write function for each file so a total of 6 functions. So last night I tried to make it so I would only have to use 1 read function and 1 write function. I got the write function to work but the read function is not. I have been looking since last night for a solution to this problem and I am fed up so any help you can give I would appreciate.
I am new to programming/python if you could not tell. Here is the code I'm using:

```
w = {} # would be past in as source

def writing(filename, source): 
    with open(filename, 'wb') as st:
        pickle.dump(source, st)

def reading(filename, source):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        source = pickle.loads(st.read())

reading('test.txt', w)
```

The error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./database.py", line 303, in <module>
   pw.check_pwd(p)
  File "./database.py", line 47, in check_pwd
    if self.pwds[self.user] == hashlib.sha512(self.pwd + self.salt).hexdigest():
KeyError: 'Codex' this was the error I was getting sorry for the bad post
```

Comment: What "problem" are you seeing? This code is syntactically correct. You need to tell us the issue and what you expect to see

Comment: I am getting a key error when trying to read from the file and then it posts the line that is trying to read from the file I did try return as suggested below but still get the same thing.

Comment: Three people answered this question when there was not a single "problem" stated until 2 minutes ago...

Comment: @Nick can you show us the error message? Fill out your question with an actual issue rather than putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what problem you are trying, but I am very confident that you want the result of the unpickling in the global `w` variable, right? Well, you cannot do it this way: when you attribute a value to the `source` variable, you are updating only the local variable `source` but the variable `w` still points to the same value. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748158/why-does-the-operator-not-change-a-list-while-append-does/10748191#10748191) may help you to understand what is happening.

There are various solutions to it. One of my favorite ones is the @katrielatex one: return the value:

```
def reading(filename, source):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        source = pickle.loads(st.read())
    return source
w = reading(filename, w)
```

Actually, you do not even need the `source` parameter:

```
def reading(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        source = pickle.loads(st.read())
        return source

w = reading(filename)
```

Another solution is [to update the dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) pointed by `source`. In this case, no return is needed:

```
def reading(filename, source):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        source.update(pickle.loads(st.read()))

reading(filename, w)
```

Also, you can make `w` a global variable inside the function (but it is the worst solution):

```
def reading(filename):
    global w
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        w = pickle.loads(st.read())

reading(filename)
```

Comment: @Nick it is great that it worked! However, I suggest you to take some time to understand why it worked and your solution did not. This is a very important aspect of working with Python (and most object-oriented languages, for that matter) Aside the link I gave above, you can see [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/287976).

Comment: Yeah just read the update link and now feel.... it was right in front of my face. I actually read that doc last night

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return source` in the second function:

```
def reading(filename, source):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        source = pickle.loads(st.read())
    return source
```

Otherwise Python will default to returning nothing (`None`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you get back a dict, your `reading()` could as well be like

```
def reading(filename, source):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as st:
        tmp = pickle.loads(st.read())
    source.update(tmp)
```

but, to be honest, the [`return` solution by katrielalex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11212408/296974) is better.

Answer (score 0):

Reading function only needs a file name and it should return something:

```
def save(filename, data): 
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)

def load(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

Example:

```
save('data.pickle', [a, b, c])
a, b, c = load('data.pickle')
```