# python is stealing objects from me

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Well I'm just learning Python and I'm experiencing some strange behavior. I guess that garbage collector is responsible for that but I'm not sure.

**SORRY LADS I MESSED UP THE QUESTION**

I wanted reproduce some weirdness I was getting while using some library without that library but I failed miserably.

So second try:

I'm using python API of Autodesk Maya. It is just python wrap around existing C++ API.

So this code:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om

Q = om.MQuaternion(1,2,3,4).conjugateIt()
P = om.MQuaternion(6,6,6,6)
print(Q[0],Q[1],Q[2],Q[3])
print(type(Q))
print(type(P))
```

produces this output:

```
(6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0)
<class 'maya.OpenMaya.MQuaternion'>
<class 'maya.OpenMaya.MQuaternion'>
```

So both `P,Q` are of type `MQuaternion` but `Q` does not hold the data it should hold.
Here you can find [documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/cpp_ref/class_m_quaternion.html) for `MQuaternion` class. `conjugateIt` is conjugation in place and returns by reference.

So what went wrong now ?

---

### Here goes the old question which is just wrong :D

In C++ I'm used to do thing like this.

```
complex<float> c = complex<float>(1,2).conjInPlace()
```

conjInPlace() is conjugation in place

But if I do something similar in python I get into trouble

```
class testClass:
        def __init__(self,_a,_b):
            self.a = _a
            self.b = _b
        def alterMe(self):
            self.b = 123

A = testClass(1,2)
A.alterMe()
print(A.a,A.b)
B = testClass(0,0)
B = testClass(3,4).alterMe()
print(B)
```

gives me output:

```
1 123
None
```

I guess that because object returned by `testClass(3,4)` is not immediately referenced by something so it gets deleted.

So why is this happening? How to watch out for this kind of things?

Comment: because you are not returning anything from your `alertme` function

Comment: You should be able to add `return self` at the bottom of your `alterMe()` function if you want your example code to work.

Comment: The answers you have gotten are correct.  You can of course `return self` at the end of `alterMe`, and I've done code like that, but it seems generally to be considered "not Pythonic" to modify and return yourself.

Comment: Good lord, if the garbage collector were that aggressive python would be a much worse language to code in.

Comment: HAHAHAHA :D I cocked up everything :D Sorry lads for such a stupid question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConjugateIt returns a reference in C++, so it's not going to return the python object correctly. Try this:

```
Q = om.MQuaternion(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)
print Q.x, Q.y, Q.z, Q.w
Q.conjugateIt()
print Q.x, Q.y, Q.z, Q.w
print "----"
P = om.MQuaternion(6,6,6,6)
print P.x, P.y, P.z, P.w

# 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
# -1.0 -2.0 -3.0 4.0
# ----
# 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0
```

UPDATED first line to reflect tom's observation

Comment: FWIW I have no idea why the swig wrapper gives a bum pointer as a return from the ConjugateIt method. *sigh*

Comment: how come that `ConjugateIt` is `void` it documentation says it is `MQuaternion &` ?

Comment: My bad - it actually returns a reference... although in python you don't need it. ConjugateIt modifies Q in place and you already have Q, so you can work around it as above.  The OpenMaya python docs http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/index.html?url=Maya_Python_API_Using_the_Maya_Python_API.htm,topicNumber=d0e654062 imply that references are all treated as pointers in Python - and it looks like the function is returning a nonsense "pointer" (if you don't call the P line, you'll see the values in Q are garbage)

Comment: FWIW, you could just use .conjugate instead of .conjugateIt to get a _new_ quaternion.

Comment: ok but I still don't get why it returns nonsence pointer?!
if I do simply 

    `Q = om.MQuaternion(1,2,3,4).conjugateIt()` 
    `print(Q[0],Q[1],Q[2],Q[3])`
I get almost right answer `(0.0, -2.0, -3.0, 4.0)` so it is pointing to the right part of memory. But the memory is not reserved for `Q` and by declaring `P` it gets overwriten. And yes I ended up using `.conjugate` but I thought it is waste I can do better with `conjugateIt`

Comment: You might want to take a look at the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534375/passing-values-in-python -- it's why its hard to translate the C++ idiom into Python. On my system, the result of conjugateIt is garbage (Q retains the right values but the result value is nonsense).  I think the behavior here is the same one they mention in the docs under the heading "Modify Parameter Values Instead of Using an Assignment"

Comment: Uff this is sooo wrong for me as C++ programmer. I'm reading the Blair Conrad [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) ansr the example with list is just so confusing. In C++ you can set eference only during initialization but as it seams to me not in Python.

Answer (score 6):

`A` is indeed altered by the `alterMe` method. But `B` is set to the return value of that method, which is `None`, not another `testClass` object.

Answer (score 2):

`alterMe` doesn't return anything - that's why you see None.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `alertMe` method to return the object it is invoked from:

```
def alterMe(self):
        self.b = 123
        return self
```

That is, `testClass(3, 4)` returns an object, but that object when invoked alertMe return None. With the above fix it will return the object again.

Answer (score 1):

In your C++ example, `conjInPlace` must still be *returning* the complex value, yes?  In your Python example, `alterMe` does not produces `None`, and so `B` is assigned the value `None`, just as if your `conjInPlace` had returned some value X, then `c` would be assigned X.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of `alterMe`:

```
return self
```

The problem here is that `alterMe` is not explicitly returning a value. If no return value is specified at the end of a function, Python returns `None` by default. This has nothing to do with garbage collection.

Comment: @Daenyth I was wondering ... what's OP expecting? `self` or `self.b`?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Given a return type of `complex<float>` from an object of `complex<float>`, then I'd guess it does a `return *this;` which would be `return self` in Python.