# Dictionaries under dictionary are copied by value not copied by reference?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the beginning I create `xls_dict` and `xml_dict`

Then wrapped the above 2 dicts into dictionary's creation. (I though it is copy be reference)

So I will load the json files into the 2 dicts.

However, I found when I exit the

`for export_file, data_dict in json_files.iteritems():` block.

the `xls_dict` and `xml_dict` are not changed.

The was not my expectation.

Where did I misunderstand ? Thanks

```
    xls = MultiLangXls(xls_path, XLS_COLUMN)
    xls_dict = xls.load()
    xml = MultiLangXML(xml_path)
    xml_dict = xml.load()

    json_files={
        "xls.json": xls_dict,
        "xml.json": xml_dict
    }

    for export_file, data_dict in json_files.iteritems():
        if os.path.isfile(export_file):
            pass
        else: # If json file not exists, then ouput the dict into json file
            with open( export_file , 'w') as f:
                json.dump(data_dict, f, encoding="utf-8")
        load_file = open(export_file).read().decode("utf-8-sig")
        data_dict = {}
        data_dict = json.loads( load_file )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data_dict` variable does refer to the same object and not to a copy. Assigning a new dict to `data_dict`, however, disconnects the variable from that object and assigns to it a brand new one.

To clear the *existing* dict, and fill it with new contents, you want to write something like this:

```
data_dict.clear()
data_dict.update(json.loads(load_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning data_dict to a new dictionary object.

See [Passing values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534375/passing-values-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Problem here:

```
data_dict = {} #You create new empty dictionary
# And rewrite it. But old dictionare are not cleaned.
data_dict = json.loads( load_file )
```

You must clean by `data_dict.clean()`